Why is my connection over ASDL better with a vpn?
I notice that the quality of my connection over ASDL seems better when I'm connected to a VPN. Is there any specific reason to this ?

Yes, Big Brother is watching :) :)

What's better about it?  I expect you mean ADSL Asynchronous Digital Subscriber Line, No?

Yes this is what I mean by ASDL. By better, I mean that I have a lot 404 error (specially when I have a lot of tabs open in my browser) when the VPN is off. Everything works fine when connected over VPN. I was wondering if that could be related to the way TCP/IP is handled over VPN, but it could be also IP Throtling (but I'm located in France and I think this is illegal, so still wondering)
